# How to clear a message after AddModuleMessage

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

If I want to add message to Module in dotnetnuke I should do this

```
DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.AddModuleMessage(Me, "Error1", DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Controls.ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.RedError)
```

but If I want to add a warning too like this

```
DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.AddModuleMessage(Me, "Error2", DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Controls.ModuleMessage.ModuleMessageType.YellowWarning)
```

I get 2 messages on my module.  How do I clear messages that were previously added with AddModuleMessage?

Answer (score 5):

Either you have to write javascript to delete those elements from client side on some action, OR they will be automatically removed on next page refresh.